# Calculate a sum based on all members of a set minus selected members of the set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

what I want to do is pretty easy I guess, but I can't figure out an easy and nice solution:

I have a sales area (first Level) which sum I would like to see in the Report, futhermore I have specific sales regions (Level three) which should allways be the same for the Report. The difference between the selected sales regions which belong to a sales area and selected sales regions of a sales area should be stated under "others".

My questions now is, what is the most easy way to do this? See the example for understanding:

> Sales Region1
>   Sales Region2
>   Sales Region3
>   Other Sales Region Sales Area 1 = Total Sales Sales Area 1- Sum(Sales Region1: Sales Region3)
>   Total Sales Sales Area 1

To specify my question I wanted to upload the samples in Pictures, but just can't.

So further explenation:

I have a datasetlike:

From all Members in one Sales Area like: `ANCESTORS([Sales Area].[Sales Area Code].&[VG1], 3 )` I want only have selected members in a list: `([Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Belgien]&[VG1].&[BEL]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Dänemark]&[VG1].&[DEN]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Spanien]&[VG1].&[ESP]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Frankreich]&[VG1].&[F1]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Frankreich]&[VG1].&[F2]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Frankreich]&[VG1].&[F3]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Finland]&[VG1].&[FIN]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Island]&[VG1].&[ISL]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Italien]&[VG1].&[ITA]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Luxemburg]&[VG1].&[LUX]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Luxemburg]&[VG1].&[NED]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Norwegen]&[VG1].&[NOR]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Portugal]&[VG1].&[POR]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Schweden]&[VG1].&[S1]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[Schweden]&[VG1].&[S2]&[VG1]+[Sales Area].[Sales Areas].[Land].&[United Kingdom]&[VG1].&[GBR]&[VG1])` and for those who are part of all I want to calculate an "Other Sum".

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: Show us your table structure, some sample data and expected results

Comment: Can you please include a sample of your Dataset and expected report output?